# PyInstaller not displaying .png img when it creates an exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a code that creates GUI using Tkinter but when I try to run PyInstaller and I create an exe file my .png image is missing from the app:

```
self.logo = PhotoImage(file = 'img01.png')

ttk.Label(self.frame_header, image = self.logo, ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, 
rowspan = 2)

ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = 'Static Data App!',style = 
'Header.TLabel').grid(row = 0, column = 1)

ttk.Label(self.frame_header, wraplength = 400,
text = ("Just click on the buttons one by one and follow the 
logic")).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

ttk.Label(self.frame_header, image = self.logo, ).grid(row = 0, column = 3, 
rowspan = 2)

self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
self.frame_content.pack()
```

The output I receive when I try to run exe file is "img.png no such file od directory" even though the img gets displayed when I run my app from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you copying the images folder to the dist folder where the .exe is?

Comment: ... I just tried to put the img into the same folder where my exe file is and it worked ... Thanks @adejongh93